# Read and value from registry and concatenate and finally assign to a variable in wix bootstrapper

Tags: variables, wix, string-concatenation, bootstrapper

I want to launch the application immediately after the installation.
My code is as follows

```
   <Variable Name="LaunchTarget" Value="C:\ProgramFiles\MySetup\MyExe.exe" />
```

If the user change the installation directory during installation then this code won't work.

My idea is to keep the directory in a registry key during installation (like `C:\ProgramFile\UserGiverName`) and in the bootstrapper program want to read this value and add the exe name with this registry key value then assign that value to the `LaunchTarget` variable..

Welcome to any good suggestion regarding this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you described if you write a custom Bootstrapper Application. However, there isn't anything built into the wixstdba that will read the registry *after* the chain is applied. I'm guessing your using the wixstdba becasue it has the concept of LaunchTarget built in.

To solve the problem, I would instead, recommend having a variable that stores the install folder (maybe call it `InstallFolder`) and pass that value from the wixstdba down to the .msi file(s) via a `MsiProperty` element. Something like:

```
<!-- Default InstallFolder to something -->
<Variable Name='InstallFolder' Value='[ProgramFilesFolder]MySetup' />

<!-- Pass InstallFolder to the MSI -->
<MsiPackage ...>
   <MsiProperty Name='INSTALLFOLDER' Value='[InstallFolder]' />
</MsiPackage>
```

Then you can set LaunchTarget to:

```
<Variable Name='LaunchTarget' Value='[InstallFolder]\MyExe.exe' />
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm new to wix. I don't know much about "wixstdba". Is that a dll? What i want to do to pass the value from wixstdba?

Comment: wixstdba is the "WiX Standard Bootstrapper Application". You can read about it's functionality in the WiX.chm.

Comment: By adding the above codes...It won't work for me...where is the variable want to add(before or after the chain)?

Comment: `LaunchTarget` you can set anywhere in the `Bundle` element. The `MsiProperty` you need to set on your `MsiPackage` elements.

Comment: But still it is not working...Can you Tel me what the value [installFolder] may return? Is it like C:\ProgramFiles\MySetup???

Comment: `InstallFolder` will be whatever you define it to be. You could define it as <Variable Name='InstallFolder' Value='[ProgramFilesFolder]MySetup' />